# Difference between login with public/private keys and certificates in ssh

Tags: ssh, authentication

I'm trying to establish the difference between two procedures that I'm using to make ssh connections.

In the first sequence of commands I do:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-copy-id user@ip
ssh user@ip
```

I believe this corresponds to a public/private key authentication with the server. I think this is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks.

The other sequences goes as follows:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa 
cat /home/login_server/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /home/login_server/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@ip -o VisualHostKey=yes
```

I think the second command is what essentially the command ssh-copy-id does. The option -i tells however where to find a private key which I didn't do before. Can I assume that this is a certified version of the above?

Comment: What’s `/home/login_server` in your setup?

Comment: @StephenKitt The home for the server I'm trying to log in

Comment: This is presented confusingly, there's not a certificate in sight, though the title refers to them, and I've no idea what "a certified version of the above" is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both approaches you’re using are similar, and they use the same authentication mechanisms. The specific differences are:

- `ssh-copy-id user@ip` will copy all local keys which aren’t yet authorised on `user@ip` to the target system, whereas your `cat` command only copies the key you’ve just created;
- `ssh user@ip` will try all available authentication keys, whereas `ssh -i ...` will only use the specified key.

The MITM issues relate to the host keys, not your own keys. That’s where `VisualHostKey` helps, since it’s easier to compare (for us humans). But that has nothing to do with the various authentication mechanisms.

Note that SSH now supports certificates too, but these are different: basically, instead of listing all authorised keys on every server, you configure servers to accept keys signed by a given certification authority.

Answer (score 2):

> I believe this corresponds to a public/private key authentication with the server.

This does one password authentication and one public key authetnication.

> I think this is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks.

If you properly check the host key, it is not vulnerable to MitM.

> I think the second command is what essentially the command ssh-copy-id does.

Yes, but `ssh-copy-id` does also other checks to make sure permissions and selinux contexts are correct. Also it does it over the network and using a `password` authentication.

> The option -i tells however where to find a private key which I didn't do before.

Yes. But the `/home/login_server/.ssh/id_rsa` is default.

> Can I assume that this is a certified version of the above?

No. It is just copying files. If the home directory is mounted over some other method (NFS, Samba or again `sshfs`), you rely on security of these protocols. Certificates are something different, as described for example here:

https://ef.gy/hardening-ssh